# Eslint error "Missing return type on function" when implementing styled component in _document.tsx (Next)

Tags: typescript, next.js, styled-components, typescript-eslint

I am currently setting up my NextJS project to use styled component and Typescript.

Following the official [NextJS doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document) I configured the `_document.tsx` file which works and looks like this:

```
import Document, { DocumentContext } from 'next/document';

import { ServerStyleSheet } from 'styled-components';

class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(ctx: DocumentContext) {
        const sheet = new ServerStyleSheet();
        const originalRenderPage = ctx.renderPage;
        try {
            ctx.renderPage = () =>
                originalRenderPage({
                    enhanceApp: (App) => (props) => sheet.collectStyles(<App {...props} />),
                });

            const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx);
            return {
                ...initialProps,
                styles: (
                    <>
                        {initialProps.styles}
                        {sheet.getStyleElement()}
                    </>
                ),
            };
        } finally {
            sheet.seal();
        }
    }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

However, now I am getting the following warning from ESLint: "Missing return type on function".

I don't want to deactivate this features in ESLint so what's the proper way to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Would adding an explicit return type to `getInitialProps` work? Could import `DocumentInitialProps` from `'next/document'` and use it for the return type of the function as `Promise<DocumentInitialProps>`.

Comment: Yes indeed! That was it, thanks! I will answer my own question!

Answer (score 2):

Ok so now that I understand TypeScript a bit better I could fix the warning.
As mentioned by @juliomalves the TS compiler is expecting a return to the function so we can write it this way:

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
    static async getInitialProps(
        ctx: DocumentContext,
    ): Promise<{
        styles: JSX.Element;
        html: string;
        head?: JSX.Element[];
    }> {
    ...
    }
```